# Using MapKit, MKMapview how can I orientate the map by aligning two coordinates vertical on the screen

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapkit

I have two coordinates that represent a portion of a route, and I want to orientate the MKMapView such that the route, `polyline` is displayed going from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen.

Currently I first calculate the angle between the two coordinates, and then rotate the map by setting the camera heading, where 90 degrees is facing north and vertically centred on the screen.

Is there perhaps an easier approach, sample code would be great in either Swift or Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I first calculate the angle between the two coordinates, and then rotate the map by setting the camera heading, where 90 degrees is facing north and vertically centred on the screen.

You've got the right idea. There's no way to set the map view's heading directly, so setting the camera heading is the right way to go. Be sure to set the map view's `rotationEnabled` property to `YES` to get the map view to use the camera's heading, and if you want to always see the map in plan view (i.e. looking straight down), you can set `pitchEnabled` to `NO`.